# How to calculate another GROUP BY with SUM in an existing query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code that shows me the below results. I need to take these results and then SUM the number in the `Count` column and then `GROUP BY` the `Week Of` so that I have a sum of intervals per `Week Of`. Is this done via a sub query? I am not sure how to accomplish this.

```
DECLARE @interval as INT = 30;
DECLARE @StartDate as datetime = '2023-01-01 00:00:00';

SELECT
    owneridname [Owner],
    CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [Week Of],
        /* Calculates the amount of minutes from the start date and the Created On date using the DATEDIFF function, then divide by 30 to get the total number of 30min increments in that time frame. */
        /* This could end up as a decimal so we use FLOOR() to get the closest integer value. */
        /* We then multiply by 30 to bring it back to the Created On's date but at the appropriate interval */
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, createdon) / CAST(@interval as decimal)) * @interval, @StartDate) as TIME(0)) [createdon_datetime_30_min_interval],
        /* Counting the number of case creation dates per interval */
    COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM incident
WHERE 
    createdon > DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY
        /* Grouping by the 30min intervals */
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, createdon) / CAST(@interval as decimal)) * @interval, @StartDate) as TIME(0)),
    owneridname,
    CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date)
ORDER BY [Owner] ASC;
```

| Owner | Week Of | Interval | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 2023-07-24 | 21:00:00 | 12 |
| Brad Pitt | 2023-07-24 | 00:30:00 | 1 |
| Brad Pitt | 2023-07-24 | 00:00:00 | 1 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-31 | 16:30:00 | 1 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-24 | 11:00:00 | 10 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-24 | 15:30:00 | 5 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-24 | 12:30:00 | 1 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-24 | 11:00:00 | 1 |
| Neil Young | 2023-07-24 | 11:30:00 | 1 |
| Mark Johnson | 2023-07-31 | 22:00:00 | 1 |
| Mark Johnson | 2023-07-31 | 22:30:00 | 1 |
| Mark Johnson | 2023-07-24 | 17:30:00 | 1 |
| Mark Johnson | 2023-07-24 | 21:30:00 | 3 |
| Mark Johnson | 2023-07-31 | 23:00:00 | 1 |

Next set of results I am looking for that show the sum of intervals per the `Week Of:

| Owner | Week Of | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 7/24/2023 | 12 |
| Brad Pitt | 7/24/2023 | 2 |
| Neil Young | 7/24/23 | 18 |
| Neil Young | 7/31/2023 | 1 |
| Mark Johnson | 7/24/2023 | 4 |
| Mark Johnson | 7/31/2023 | 3 |

Comment: You could insert your values you have above into a temp table you create, then do your new group by off that, or use a subquery.  Sometimes temp tables are better for performance and readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap your query with outer query.

```
DECLARE @interval as INT = 30;
DECLARE @StartDate as datetime = '2023-01-01 00:00:00';

SELECT [Owner], [Week Of], SUM([Count])
FROM (
    SELECT
        owneridname [Owner],
        CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [Week Of],
            /* Calculates the amount of minutes from the start date and the Created On date using the DATEDIFF function, then divide by 30 to get the total number of 30min increments in that time frame. */
            /* This could end up as a decimal so we use FLOOR() to get the closest integer value. */
            /* We then multiply by 30 to bring it back to the Created On's date but at the appropriate interval */
        CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, createdon) / CAST(@interval as decimal)) * @interval, @StartDate) as TIME(0)) [createdon_datetime_30_min_interval],
            /* Counting the number of case creation dates per interval */
        COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM incident
    WHERE 
        createdon > DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()) 
    GROUP BY
            /* Grouping by the 30min intervals */
        CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, createdon) / CAST(@interval as decimal)) * @interval, @StartDate) as TIME(0)),
        owneridname,
        CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date)
) d
GROUP BY [Owner], [Week Of]
ORDER BY [Owner] ASC;
```

Comment: This worked and did what I wanted. A sub query was in fact the way to go - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @interval as INT = 30;
DECLARE @StartDate as datetime = '2023-01-01 00:00:00';
    
WITH interval_count AS (
    SELECT
        owneridname [Owner],
        CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [Week Of],
        COUNT(*) [Count]
    FROM incident
    WHERE 
        createdon > DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY
        CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, createdon) / CAST(@interval as decimal)) * @interval, @StartDate) as TIME(0)),
        owneridname,
        CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date)
)
SELECT 
    Owner,
    [Week Of],
    SUM(Count) AS Sum
FROM interval_count
GROUP BY Owner, [Week Of]
ORDER BY Owner ASC, [Week Of] ASC;
```